# Issue connection with PHP to my distant database (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, centos

We use 2 servers on CentOS. One with the PHP Code and the other with our database (MariaDB).
We tried to connect them, but doesn't work in PHP and work with CLI Mysql, with the same credential.
We created a special user to connect.
We use a custom framework to connect to the database.

Everything work when we are on local (on a physical machine, not on server)

PHP version : 5.4.16

We tried a phpinfo(); : Mysql and Mysqli is activated.
Connection to the MySQL serveur with CLI work.

```php
    define('DBNAME', 'start-up');
    define('DBHOST', '10.13.200.13');
    define('DBUSER', 'gestions');
    define('DBPASSWORD', 'gestionPass');
```

From the custom framework :

```php
    protected static $db = false;
    private static $last;
    private static $prep;

    //La dernière requete effectuée
    private static $error = null;

    private static $user;
    private static $password;
    private static $name;
    private static $host;

 public function __construct()
    {
        if (self::$db === false) {
            $dsn            = 'mysql:dbname=' . DBNAME . ';host=' . DBHOST;
            self::$user     = DBUSER;
            self::$password = DBPASSWORD;
            self::$name     = DBNAME;
            self::$host     = DBHOST;

            self::$db = parent::__construct($dsn, self::$user, self::$password);
        }
    }
```

```sql
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             ------------------------------------+
| Grants for gestions@10.13.200.13                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             ------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON . TO 'gestions'@'10.13.200.13' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*XXXXXX' |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON database.* TO 'gestions'@'10.13.200.13'                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             ------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I don't really know what to show to you.

I expect to connect my PHP to my MySQL server.

Thanks a lot !

--- EDIT ---

That's a mistake. I put my local code, the code on the VM is the real IP.

Adding my user (Probably the problem ?)

Comment: if you use different host for the db, then it's not localhost. change host accordingly

Comment: This line should change `define('DBHOST', 'localhost');` You probably need the ip address of the remote server instead of localhost. Remember, localhost means "here on this machine"

Comment: As well as adding the IP address within DBHOST definition, on the MySQL side you'll have to make sure that the same user has privileges from that IP address. Otherwise, the user will be denied access even when the IP address has been entered correctly.

Comment: Yup. You're trying to access your server by having DBHOST, 'localhost'...

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, i've edit my code. On my production server it's already the good ip address !

Comment: What's `self::$db`?

Comment: Hi Anuga,
It's a parameter :)
```php
    protected static $db = false;
    private static $last;
    private static $prep;

    //La dernière requete effectuée
    private static $error = null;

    private static $user;
    private static $password;
    private static $name;
    private static $host;
```